# How to use https with Azure Functions locally with Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, ssl, https, azure-functions

I'm developing a small application, the web client is using https, making AJAX calls to the Azure Functions v1 application running locally in VS, the Azure functions app is written in C#.

I haven't found any info on running the Azure functions project **locally** over https. Is it supported? the client cannot make requests to the Azure Functions app through http.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a tunnel like https://ngrok.com/ . You run their client locally, their service exposes a https endpoint on the cloud that tunnels to localhost via their client. I've used this before, and it was easier than trying to get my local web server to accept https. 
That also solves the problem of receiving webhooks on localhost. While webhooks can't point to localhost, they can point to the cloud endpoint, and it will tunnel back to localhost.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out.